# Is it enough to list a set in a defined way to ensure its countability?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove that the set of positive rational numbers are countable. I shall arrange the positive rationals $p/q$, in the order of their sum of their numerators and denominators. So, $1/1$ would be, in our scheme, have its sum 2, $1/2$, $2/1$ have their sum (of num. and den.) 3, $3/1$,$1/3$,$2/2$ would have their sum 4, and so on.

If we list the rationals in order of their sum of numerators and denominators, omitting the ones already listed, we would get something like:

$$
1, 1/2,2/1, 1/3,3/1,1/4,4/1,2/3,3/2 \cdots$$

Though, there isn’t a one-to-one correspondence (because, for example, 5 is mapped by 4 elements), yet a proper list (that is a list which is constructed through a rule) in itself can be numbered. So, is listing rationals in that way shows their countability?

Kindly help me in resolving this doubt.

Comment: Why do you claim that “$5$ is mapped by $4$ elements”?

Comment: Instead of considering a correspondence between $5$ and all of $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{4}{1}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, and $\frac{3}{2}$ (i.e. between $a+b$ and $\frac{a}{b}$), consider matching $a$ with $0$, $\frac{1}{2}$ with $1$, $\frac{2}{1}$ with $2$, $\frac{1}{3}$ with $3$, etc.

Comment: If you can generate an infinite list in such a way that eventuall every element of the set will appear in the list , then you can be sure that the set is countable. This is here the case.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I couldn’t come up with any explicit function of any kind, so I simply assumed $$f(p/q) = p+q$$ and thus, I claimed 5 was mapped by 4 elements. 

With the scheme defined above, can I write an explicit bijection?

Comment: @C7X Yes, that’s exactly what the list means.

Comment: @Peter Okay, then listing in a proper way is enough. Thanks.

Comment: @DeltaPsi There is a similar (but not identical) map from a pair of natural numbers to a natural number [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

Answer (score 1):

**I think there is a small part missing in that argument.**

You consider the map
$$
f \colon\mathbb Q_{\geq0}\to \mathbb N, \frac{p}{q} \mapsto p+q,\quad\text{where }gcd(p,q)=1.
$$

Then you consider the preimages $f^{-1}(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and 'list' the rationals as
$$
f^{-1}(0),\, f^{-1}(1),\,f^{-1}(2),\,f^{-1}(3),\,\dots
$$
which is to say that $\mathbb Q_{\geq 0} = \bigcup_n f^{-1}(n)$. Now this is obviously a countable union.

**However you still need to prove that** each $f^{-1}(n)$ is finite (or countable, depending on what you can use)